# Json строки в ресурсах String

Tags: javascript, json, android-studio, строки, recyclerview

Хочу ввести в приложение локализацию (новые языки: Анг, Рус, Латинь), но у меня RecycleViewAdapter берет строки с файла json как прописать в скрипте не саму строку которая должна быть а ссылку на ресурс типа `R.string.main` или нужно менять код адаптера а в скрипте это сделать не возможно
Вот фрагмент скрипта:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "question_category": "1",
      "category_name": "Пульмонологія"
    },
    {
      "question_category" : "2",
      "category_name" : "Гастроентерологія"
    },
    {
      "question_category": "3",
      "category_name": "Гематологія"
    }
  ]
}
```

и как сделать в обычному RecycleView отправку на строки в ресурсах

```
    private void initImageBitmaps(){
            //0
            mImageUrls.add("https://u.livelib.ru/reader/vwvw2008/o/fmhclhxy/o-o.jpeg");
            mNames.add(R.string.material_1); **Не работает**
            //1
            mImageUrls.add("https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2015/01/17/589833/ae71f6d11c0ad38688daa0e17dd9b8be.jpg");
            mNames.add("Біологічна та загальна хімія");
            //2
            mImageUrls.add("https://ukrinnovate.com/upload/website-science-or-innovation-article-image-201803191200.jpg");
            mNames.add("Гістологія");
            //3
            mImageUrls.add("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/36spQsZ5pqQ/maxresdefault.jpg");
            mNames.add("Загальної гігієна та екологія");
            //4
            mImageUrls.add("https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/kletki_mikrobiologiya_struktura_113059_1920x1080.jpg");
            mNames.add("Мікробіологія");
            //5
            mImageUrls.add("https://dekart-school.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/biologiya-oge.jpg");
            mNames.add("Медична біологія");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        mImageUrls.add("https://u.livelib.ru/reader/vwvw2008/o/fmhclhxy/o-o.jpeg");
        mNames.add(R.string.material_1); **Не работает**

        Меняем на

        mImageUrls.add("https://u.livelib.ru/reader/vwvw2008/o/fmhclhxy/o-o.jpeg");
        mNames.add(getString(R.string.physiology)); **Работает**
```